# Error java.lang.NullPointerException at org.client.andorid.MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(MyLocationListener.java:29)

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, location

i have got this error getting location. i send manually coordiantes through emulator control when application starting but still got this error my code is

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


//for getting location
        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ll = new MyLocationListener(etTextOut);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0 , 0, ll);
}
```

and my location class is

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

EditText etTextOut;

public MyLocationListener(EditText etTextOut) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.etTextOut = etTextOut;
}

//public TextView tv;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    loc.getLongitude();
            loc.getLatitude();

    String msg = "Latitude:" + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude:" + loc.getLongitude();

     etTextOut.setText(msg);



}
```

i want to set my coordiantes in edittext of the main class and send it over  to PC through socket

Comment: Where do you initialize etTextOut before calling the MyLocationListener ctor?

Comment: in main class   EditText etTextOut = null;

Comment: Well, then that's your null pointer exception.  If it's null, you can't very well do etTextOut.setText on it, can you?

Comment: first i didn't initialize it gave the same error then i initialize it with  null then same error

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Did you expect it to magically become a valid EditText without you initializing it?